# How to convert nested object to array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a data that the structure is like below:

```
var data = {
    0: {
        user: 1,
        job: "call center"
    },
    1: {
        user: 2,
        job: "programmer"
    }
}
```

Now I want to convert them to array of objects that looks like this:

```
[Object {user : 1, job  : call center}, {user : 2, job  : programmer} ]
```

Is it possible? How can I convert them.  Any help, thanks.

Comment: `Is it possible?` yes

Comment: what should I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your Object creation has poor syntax
2. Below shows you how to do this with a simple for loop, but makes a lot of assumptions (e.g., your object keys are labeled correctly).  I would ordinarily use `map`, but feel that may not be as easy/straightforward for you to understand; so the loop should be simple enough to follow.

---

```
var data =  { 0:{
                  user : 1,
                  job  : 'call center'
              },
              1:{
                  user : 2,
                  job  : 'programmer'
              }
            };


var arr  = [],
    keys = Object.keys(data);

for(var i=0,n=keys.length;i<n;i++){
  var key  = keys[i];
  arr[key] = data[key];
}
```

Comment: Crockford recommended to use `forEach` over traditional `for` loop.

Comment: @RahulDesai: Then ignore Crockford.

Comment: I like crockford, but think it's a matter of preference, whatever is easier to understand.  The `for..in` may also be applicable, but it's difficult to determine what the OP's level is at.  My default is to go to the traditional `for`, but yes foreach would also work.  `map` is still preferred as it creates the array as a result of the iteration

Comment: Try adding a length property (m + 1) and run it through `Array.prototype.slice.call(object)`. 99% less hacky and less work.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `map`

```
 var array = $.map(data , function(value, index) {
     return [value];
 });
```

You can also do it without jQuery:

```
var array = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) { return obj[k] });
```

Comment: FYI - There is no jQuery tag for this question.

Comment: Or wait, you are abusing jQuery's concat-map functionality (that is misnamed `map`) that can enumerate objects… Clever.

Comment: @RahulDesai what about now?

Comment: You don't really need the `[]` around `value`, and in fact you can just do `$.map(data, Object)`

Comment: The thing worth noting is that the *Object.keys.map* will be creating an array in the order the key is encountered, but the index/key of the object will not necessarily be the index in the array.  So if an object has two keys (e.g., `0` and `3`).  A `for` loop would result in an array with 2 values in the corresponding positions and a bunch of `undefined`s in between (i.e., `[{},undef,undef,{}]`) .  A map will just take the values and stick them in an array set (`[{},{}]`).  There needs to be more clarification about the source and destination of the data.

Comment: hmm obj[k] is data[k] right. Use copy paste carefully.

Answer (score 1):

```js
Object.values(data)
```

yields

```js
[{user: 1, job: 'call center'}, {user: 2, job: 'programmer'}]
```