# how Can I convert nested objects to array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert the nested object to array

below is the example I am trying 
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: {
    d : "y"
  }
};

I want my result to be [a,b,c.d](needed keys not vlaues)

Comment: Just prepend `object1.` to these and you have your array literal?

Comment: You want to recursively collect all the keys from your nested object? Is that it?

Comment: Check out this related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280216/how-to-convert-nested-object-to-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is **Object.keys()**

You can find more data about it at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

The below `collect()` function uses [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to recursively collect all the **keys** from your object:

```js
const collect = (x) => typeof x === 'object' && x !== null
    ? Object.entries(x).reduce((a, [k, v]) => [...a, k, ...collect(v)], [])
    : [];

const keys = collect({ a: 'somestring', b: 42, c: { d : "y" } });

console.log(keys); // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

If you want to collect **nested keys** (with dot notation):

```js
const collect = (x, path) => typeof x === 'object' && x !== null
    ? Object.entries(x).reduce((a, [k, v]) => [
        ...a, 
        ...collect(v, path ? `${path}.${k}` : k)], [])
    : [path];

const keys = collect({ a: 'somestring', b: 42, c: { d : "y" } });

console.log(keys); // ["a", "b", "c.d"]
```

If you want to recursively collect **values** instead of keys:

```js
const collect = (x) => typeof x === 'object' && x !== null
    ? Object.entries(x).reduce((a, [_, v]) => [...a, ...collect(v)], [])
    : [x];

const values = collect({ a: 'somestring', b: 42, c: { d : "y" } });

console.log(values); // ["somestring", 42, "y"]
```

Comment: OP shows `[a,b,c.d]`, so yeah, that's 3 elements with `c.d` being the last. Not only that, but those are just the properties. If you want those, they're in the last `i` argument of my example, by the way.

Comment: @StackSlave The question is unclear so I asked for clarification. Since it doesn't seem to be forthcoming, I answered what I understood the question to be. Thanks for the downvote. I've updated my answer to include a solution according to your interpretation of the question.

Comment: Thanks Robby, sorry for not clear on the question. I just need a key pair not values [a,b,c.d] (keys only)

Comment: @PraveenAlluri Added a snippet in the middle for the nested keys (with dot notation) scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the furthest value into the Object, then it's like:

```js
function walkRecursive(walkable, walkFunc){
  if(typeof walkable === 'object'){
    let v;
    if(walkable instanceof Array){
      for(let i=0,l=walkable.length; i<l; i++){
        v = walkable[i];
        if(typeof v === 'object'){
          walkRecursive(v, walkFunc);
        }
        else{
          walkFunc(v, i, walkable);
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      for(let i in walkable){
        v = walkable[i];
        if(typeof v === 'object'){
          walkRecursive(v, walkFunc);
        }
        else{
          walkFunc(v, i, walkable);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 
}
const a = [];
walkRecursive({a:'somestring', b:42, c:{d:'y'}}, (v, i, o)=>{
  console.log('object: '+o);
  console.log('property: '+i);
  console.log('value: '+v);
  console.log('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
  a.push(v);
});
console.log('-------------------------------------------');
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries`, `reduce` with recursive approach.

```js
const obj = { a: 'somestring', b: 42, c: { d: "y" } };

const getKeysArr = (obj, prefix) => {
  var arr = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (["string","number"].includes(typeof value)) {
      acc.push(prefix ? `${prefix}.${key}` : key);
    } else {
      acc.push(getKeysArr(value, key));
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return arr.flat();
};

console.log(getKeysArr(obj, ''));
```